# Who is the "dinosaur guy with the nasty attitude"?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

It has been a while, so I can't seem to remember, but who is Beerus referring to, when he is talking about "*that dinosaur guy with the nasty attitude*" that he asked to destroy Earth?

[image: "You mean that one planet I had asked that dinosaur guy with the nasty attitude to destroy for me?"]

Comment: More than likely it's a yet to be introduced character, but it might be Bibidi, who knows?

Comment: If you took this from the Manga Stream, please note that they take a lot of liberties with their translations, so they are not always accurate.

Answer (score 1):

From [Stark Uprising's review](http://starkuprising.blogspot.in/2015/07/dragon-ball-super-chapter-2-gokus-defeat.html?m=1) of *Dragon Ball Super* Chapter 2:

> Also, note how Beerus says he asked "the dinosaur guy with the nasty attitude" to destroy Earth. In "Battle of Gods" Beerus says this a little differently--he says he is the one who destroyed all the dinosaurs on Earth. This could be an error in translation, or it could be Toyotaro changing it up, since we all know dinosaurs are still alive and well on planet Earth in Dragon Ball (I explain how that is at the bottom of my "Battle of Gods" post). Maybe this "dinosaur guy" is someone we'll meet eventually? Maybe it's a reference to King Piccolo or Babadi? Or maybe it's just an off-handed joke to a Godzilla-like kaiju that'll never be followed up on.

It could well be a translation error as [Dragon Ball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Beerus) confirms what Beerus said in *Battle of the Gods*:

> Beerus also claims that he once went to Earth, and dinosaurs took a rude attitude toward him, so he wiped them out.

This could be revealed in the future or be kept as a mystery element. Only Akira sensei knows how its going to be.

Comment: Toriyama is not known for his consistency. This is probably just an error: they must have forgotten that dinosaurs are alive in their world

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory the dinosaur guy maybe kami before he extracted piccolo from him but then he saw the beauty in earth and decided to protect it rather than destroy it that's just my guess though

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Azala from Chrono Trigger http://chrono.wikia.com/wiki/Azala
I think Beerus make a few other Chrono Trigger jokes like he destroyed the time ship Epoch. That's why I think he's talking about Azala the dinosaur guy with a rude disposition.